# How to add function in element of JQgrid like Onchange event in select box

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I am Using `Jqgrid` and in edit mode I am using 
 function in element of `JQgrid` like `Onchange` event in select box

Code is like this

```
{name:'tipo_norma',index:'tipo_norma', editable:true, 
width:'90',align:'center',edittype:'select',editoptions: 
{dataUrl:'../ajax/selectNorma.php' }}
```

I want to add `myfunction(`) in `Onchange` event of `tipo_norma` combobox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the dataEvent in [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions)

```
    editoptions: { dataEvents: [
{ type: 'change', fn: function(e) {myfunction(); } },

]}
```

Comment: Thnaks for understating my problem

Comment: Yes Ofcaurse Thankyou very very very  much @Kris

Comment: I have not enough credit to give you Vote so cant give you vote  thank you very much once again........

Comment: Thanks mate, you are my life saver!